# Getting confused with rules of sqrts and negatives.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have to simplify: $-\sqrt{(2x + 1)^6}$
What I was able to simplify that down to is $-(2x+1)^3$, however, I think I'm simplifying the inside of the square root wrong. And if I was right, what happens with the negative when I foil it out 3 times? Will it be added in the end?

Comment: Because $(2x+1)^6$ is positive, technically $-\sqrt{(2x+1)^6}=-|2x+1|^3$.

Comment: Foiling out isn't simplifying.  Foiling out is complicating.  $(2x+1)^3$ is more simple than than  $8x^3 + 12x^2 + 6 x + 1$.  So *DON'T* foil it out three times it the end.

Answer (score 2):

Restricting to $\mathbb{R}$?

$$-\sqrt{(2x+1)^6}=-|(2x+1)^3|=-|2x+1|^3$$

Comment: What do you do with the negative sign in the last step?

Comment: @john Do nothing.

Comment: @john The negative sign is the very last operation to apply; making this more explicit with brackets, the expression is $-(\lvert 2x+1 \rvert^3)$. You can't make it simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in \mathbb{R}$

$-\sqrt{(2x + 1)^6} = -|2x + 1|^3$

$x \geq -0.5$

$-\sqrt{(2x + 1)^6} = -(2x + 1)^3$

The negative sign is outside the absolute value and outside the parenthesis.

So the result is negative for any $x$ except for $-0.5$, if that is what wonder about.

John, with my answer i was trying to explain for what values your solution are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$-\sqrt{whatever}$ requires $whatever \ge 0$ so we must first determine which values of $x$ are a allowed so that we can be assured $(2x+1)^6 \ge 0$.

As $6$ is even $whichever^6 \ge 0$ so $(2x + 1)^6 \ge 0$ for all $x$ and $-\sqrt{(2x+1)^6}$ is defined for all $x$.

Now $\sqrt{whatsoever^{2n}} = |whatsoever^n| = |whatsoever|^n$.

[BTW.  If $n$ is odd.  And $whatsoever \ge 0$, $whatsoever^n \ge 0$ and $|whatsoever|^n = whatsoever^n$.  If $whatsoever < 0$ then $whatsoever^n < 0$ so $|whatsoever|^n = -whatsoever^n > 0$.]

So $-\sqrt{(2x + 1)^6} = -|2x + 1|^3$.

[And $-|2x + 1|^3 = -(2x + 1)^3 \le 0$ if $2x + 1 \ge 0$, and  $-|2x + 1|^3 = (2x + 1)^3 < 0$ if $2x + 1 < 0$.]